# DraftJS - change link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I use example to create/remove links. https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/examples/draft-0-10-0/link/link.html

I understand how to create and remove links.

How to change link?

I can check if caret on link:

```
const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
const startKey = editorState.getSelection().getStartKey();
const startOffset = editorState.getSelection().getStartOffset();
const blockWithLinkAtBeginning = contentState.getBlockForKey(startKey);
const linkKey = blockWithLinkAtBeginning.getEntityAt(startOffset);
if (linkKey) {
  linkInstance = contentState.getEntity(linkKey);
  if (linkInstance.getData().url) {
    ...
  }
}
```

And I need to get link text/html and change `url`. I checked `replaceData`, but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post but just in case someone else stumbles upon it, you can use:

`contentState.replaceEntityData(linkKey, { url: newUrl });`

https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-content-state/#replaceentitydata